# How to properly send FormData() with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

There seems to be a problem when I try to send my FormData with AJAX from my **LTS server** (*not on my local machine*). I suspect that FormData is not supported to all browser but it does work perfectly on my local machine with the same browser I used when I tried it on my server (LTS). I'm a bit lost here and don't know what to do.

To explain further:

index

```
<form class="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <input id="image-value" data-id="{{id}}" name="{{picture}}" class="image-box-{{id}}" data-type="{{type}}" type="file" value="{{picture}}" />
    <p id="{{id}}" class="label" >Update</p>
</form>
```

I need to get the file here and upload it into a server directory

script

```
$('[id="image-value"]').change(function(e) {

var data = new FormData();
var file_data = this.files[0];
data.append('file', file_data);

e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: './someController/upload_picture/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if (data.success == true) {
            console.log(data.image_name);
        } else {
            var error = data.error_message;
            $(".question-message").fadeIn("fast").html(error);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});

});
```

controller

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $config['upload_path'] = './data/picDir/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
}
function upload_picture() {
    if ($this->check_authorization()) {
        if ($this->ion_auth->get_user_id()) {
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "image_name" => $data["file_name"],
                    "success" => true
                ));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "success" => false,
                    "error_message" => $this->upload->display_errors()
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when triggered, the request just keeps on waiting for a response from the php controller which I think is not responding.

Comment: Try removing the dot in the url from the ajax request and try again.

Comment: I dont see any problem with the directory of my controller from the url. it works fine when `data: data` is not passed

Answer (score 0):

I believe your "echo json_encode..." should be in a response - something like $this->response(json_encode...). echo will not return a response to the ajax request. Please, check your framework or lib for the correct response and share it.

Comment: note that this is working perfectly on my local machine. i think the problem is here `data = new FormData()`

Comment: can please set the data in a different way and try again